# Shared Memory Interface between Windows 64 bits and 32 bits

Tags: c++, pointers, 32bit-64bit

I need to write code in Windows 7 (64 bits) that executes a 32-bits program that has a Shared Memory Interface (SMI). More precisely, the program I am coding writes into the SMI and the 32-bits program reads from this SMI.

The first problem that I have is that I don't have access to the source code of the 32-bit program, problem that can't be solved. The second problem is that the SMI stores the address of the information that is written. This pointed is stored as a based pointer using the following code:

```
gpSharedBlock->m_pData[uiDataPointer] = (char __based(gpSharedBlock)*)pData;
```

Were pData is a pointer to the data we are writing, and gpSharedBlock->m_pData[i] points to the i^th element stored.

Probably from here you have already noticed the problem; a pointer in W32 is 4 bytes while a pointer in W64 is 8 bytes. Then, since the value stored is a 64 bit pointer,  the value finally read by the 32-bits program is not the desired one.

My question is: is there a way to do a translation of the 64-bit address to a 32-bit address such that the program that is running reads the correct information?

I have read about WOW64, and I suppose that the W32 program is running under it, but I don't know how to take advantage of that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `__based` pointer is a numeric offset from another pointer.  It is effectively a virtual pointer interpretted at runtime.

A pointer is 8 bytes in 64-bit, so to be compatible with the 32-bit program, you will have to declare the pointer members of the SharedBlock type in your 64-bit code to use 4-bit integers instead of pointers, eg:

```
struct sSharedBlock
{
    int32_t m_pData[...];
};
```

`pData` is `__based` on `gpSharedBlock`, so the value of `pData` is a relative offset from the value of `gpSharedBlock`.  Use that fact to determine the actual byte offset of your data block relative to the `gpSharedBlock` memory block, and then store that offset value into `m_pData[]` as an integer.  That is what the SMI memory block is actually expecting anyway - an offset, not a real pointer.  The `__based` keyword is just a fancy way of handling offsets using pointers without doing the offset calculations manually in code.

The original code is effectively the same as the following without needing the `__based` keyword:

```
gpSharedBlock->m_pData[uiDataPointer] = (int32_t) ( ((char*)pData) - ((char*)gpSharedBlock) );
```